# Cant log in with trinity wallet deskop on Win 10 64bit

Tags: wallet

So I generated a new Seed and now i would like to log in, but whenever I enter my password I get following error:
Node returned an error while fetching your account information, change node
Whenever I change node, I get the same error...
How can I fix this problem?